# How to write an XML file with a for loop?

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop

I am trying to do a quick program that creates a very simple XML file.  I want to create an XML file that uses a 'for loop' to create a portion of the XML several times.  When I build I get an error saying " Invalid expression term 'for'.  I check my parenthesis balance and it does seem to check out.

Does anyone know what this error means?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        XDocument myDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0" ,"utf-8","yes"),
        new XElement("Start"),

        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
                         new XElement("Entry", 
                             new XAttribute("Address", "0123"),
                             new XAttribute("default", "0"),

                        new XElement("Descripion", "here is the description"),

                        new XElement("Data", "Data goes here ")

                );

            }
        );

        }
```

Comment: that could be the problem, but is there another method I could use?

Comment: That definitely is the problem

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: This does not compile. You might want to read-up on how arguments work in c# and XElement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're currently trying to use a `for` loop in the middle of a statement. That's not going to work.

Options:

- Use `Enumerable.Range` to create a range of values, and then transform that using `Select`:

  ```
  XDocument myDoc = new XDocument(
      new XDeclaration("1.0" ,"utf-8","yes"),
      // Note that the extra elements are *within* the Start element
      new XElement("Start",
          Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
                    .Select(i => 
                         new XElement("Entry", 
                             new XAttribute("Address", "0123"),
                             new XAttribute("default", "0"),
                             new XElement("Descripion", "here is the description"),
                             new XElement("Data", "Data goes here ")))
  );
  ```
- Create the document first, and add the elements in a loop

  ```
  XDocument myDoc = new XDocument(
      new XDeclaration("1.0" ,"utf-8","yes"),
      new XElement("Start"));
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) 
  {
      myDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Entry",
                         new XAttribute("Address", "0123"),
                         new XAttribute("default", "0"),
                         new XElement("Descripion", "here is the description"),
                         new XElement("Data", "Data goes here "));
  }
  ```

Comment: That's Sir Jon Skeet talking there!

Comment: When I use this method  I get a run time error saying this would create an incorrectly structured document.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Serialization. It's just easier to work with IMO.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813